# Create nodes using the kubernetes API

Tags: nodes, kubernetes

I noticed that there is an api available for generating a node/s using yaml/json.

So far my attempts have failed however, as i get: `2015/07/17 16:07:54 http: proxy error: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443: connection refused`.

Note that I am using the kubectl proxy to access the API: `kubectl proxy --port=8080 &`

I have managed to create replication controllers and services using the API, but I am stuck on this part. In an attempt to bypass the API, I have modified the config-default.sh file in kubernetes/cluster/gce, and I tried to run it using php. I received the following response: `Can't find gcloud in PATH.  Do you wish to install the Google Cloud SDK? [Y/n]`. I dont receive this error when I run cluster/kube-up from my terminal.

Can anyone that has done this please assist?

### Update/Edit

After playing around a bit, and using  [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.md) link, I managed to create a node for a short period of time before it was deleted(Or dissapeared).

It turns out that I only created the (abstract?) concept/service for a node, and the  [Kubernetes Controller Manager Server](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.md) took it down after not finding the resources allocated for it?

I then found this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/3155) by lavalamp, quote:

> *@abonas I think eventually k8s will need to run both ways: scenario a: User provisions node, calls POST to inform k8s of node existence.
>   scenario b: User call POST to indicate desire for node; node-manager
>   contacts cloud provider to allocate & provision a new node. Right now
>   we only do a.*

This post was made in January this year though, so can anyone officially comment if this is possible or not using any tool available?

Comment: Is `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` the ip address of the kubernetes master? The address of a service visible in `kubectl get services`? Something else?

Comment: @larsks - couldnt replicate that after friday for some reason, but the update above should negate the neccessity to resolve that issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which API are you referring to? There's an API for a node to register itself with the cluster, but the apiserver itself won't actually spin up any new nodes for you.

If you are running on GCE / GKE, you can add new nodes to your cluster by resizing the managed instance group that contains your nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the RESTful API. I was referring to using the example listed here: http://kubernetes.io/third_party/swagger-ui/#!/v1/createNode.

Is there any way to resize the cluster as needed? I would like to be able to use the RESTful API for this to add or remove extra nodes as needed.

Comment: That API is used to create a node in the master's data model (e.g. when a new node registers itself). The master doesn't (yet) have a way to reach out to the cloud provider and provision new resources to grow the cluster. This needs to be done out of band, e.g. using the MIG API (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/manager/) on GCE.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually decided to edit the values in: `kubernetes/cluster/gce/config-default.sh` using php.

I created a script in the root kubernetes directory and added the following lines:

```
export PATH="/Users/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
cluster/kube-up.sh
```

I then ran the script from php, and hey presto :) Cluster creation from php.

It doesnt use the RESTful API, but it works.